# Insert Data into a Array periodically JS(react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple array which contains objects like the following -

```
Array:{
  o1:{
    }
  o2:{
    }
  o3:{
    }
  ......
  o100:{
    }
}
```

So here I have an object -

```
OBJECT:{

  }
```

Which I need to insert into the array periodically - like after every 5 items the new object should be inserted.

So how should I insert it into the array? The data in the existing index should not be overwritten.

Anyone can give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: are you wanting to just add an item to the array? like `array.push()`?

Comment: yes i want to add an item but a single item should be added after ever 5 objects that are already present in the array. and the existing items at that index should not be overwritten

Comment: Confused by what you mean "a single item should be added after ever 5 objects that are already present in the array"? Can you post an example of how the final result should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the use case but it looks like you want to use the `splice` [javascript array method]. If you have your complete `Array` object, you can loop over it with something like this:

```
const step = 5;
for (var i = step; i < yourArrayObject.length; i += step) {
  yourArrayObject.splice(i, 0, objectToInsert)
}
```

This will take your completed `Array` object and insert the object every `step` places.  Be aware that this code will mutate the original `Array` object.

Comment: thanx this was exactly what i wanted

Comment: this is returning an empty array

Comment: i got around this using slice and then splice